# Sending a lot of small messages via WCF using the net.tcp binding

Tags: wcf, net.tcp

When sending a lot of small messages (size is smaller than TCP packet size) via WCF using a net.tcp binding, is each message sent as a separate TCP packet or can a single TCP packet contain data of different messages?

Comment: You can try to find the relevant spec and find out whether it has been defined or is left to the operating system, or you can try to analyze the behavior by setting up a test project and analyzing the traffic with a packet inspector like Wireshark.

Comment: While this is a valid question I'm not sure WCF has any bearing on the behaviour that you will ultimately observe. (ie you could use raw sockets and probably see the same behaviour).  To my knowledge WCF isnt going to have any control over any packet size in the network stack thus your question can be more generic as to what happens when you send multiple packets that are smaller than the MTU and the answer to this is most likely OS dependant.